# Attaching an interpretor for Java

Tags: java

I plan to do some independent applications in Java for some very restrictive systems in terms of hardware. It is possible to write and compile Java code to add a small interpreter that they behave like made ​​executable Python program?

Comment: This isn't clear; are you asking how to write a Python interpreter in Java?

Comment: I asking for a method to create an independent application but not purposed from start to be executable. If I want to do that I compiled directly with gcj. For example how can I use Java code on a microcontroller with flash memory as small.

Comment: So, you mean, for instance, to run a jar on a hardware platform which does not have a native JRE and want to do that JRE yourself?

Comment: But to add a "small interpreter" to the JRE you still need a JVM; it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Still looks cryptic. Can you give us an idea of HOW SMALL is that environment? Number of Bits, type of Architecture (Harvard / Turing), RAM, Stack and Kinds of Storage (Flash / whatever)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMX? Technically, you could declare a MBean and invoke methods inside a JVM. That would be the recommended way (although we're not sure about how much constrained your environment wants to be)

That could include accessing the Scripting Runtime and evaluate expressions.

An alternate would be to consider something like Crash (http://www.crashub.org/)